# CNN+LSTM for Video Classification

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, classification, lstm

I am attempting to produce a model that will accept multiple video frames as input and provide a label as output (a.k.a. video classification). I have seen code similar to the below in several locations for performing this tasks. I have a point of confusion however because in the ‘out, hidden = self.lstm(x.unsqueeze(0))’ line, out will ultimately only hold the output for the last frame once the for loop is completed, therefore the returned x at the end of the forward pass would be based solely on the last frame, yes? What makes this architecture different than processing the last frame alone? Is a CNN-LSTM model an appropriate architecture for this type of problem in the first place?

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torchvision.models import resnet101

class CNNLSTM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_classes=2):
        super(CNNLSTM, self).__init__()
        self.resnet = resnet101(pretrained=True)
        self.resnet.fc = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(self.resnet.fc.in_features, 300))
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=300, hidden_size=256, num_layers=3)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(256, 128)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, num_classes)
       
    def forward(self, x_3d):
        hidden = None
        for t in range(x_3d.size(1)):
            with torch.no_grad():
                x = self.resnet(x_3d[:, t])  
            out, hidden = self.lstm(x.unsqueeze(0))         

        x = self.fc1(out.squeeze())
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x
```

Comment: do you understand what an LSTM is? do you understand that it has internal state? those questions should not be answered with "yes" until you've reviewed thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get some help on another forum. Below is an architecture that will resolve the issues I was correct in worrying about.

```
class CNNLSTM(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, num_classes=2):
    super(CNNLSTM, self).__init__()
    self.resnet = resnet101(pretrained=True)
    self.resnet.fc = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(self.resnet.fc.in_features, 300))
    self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=300, hidden_size=256, num_layers=3)
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(256, 128)
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, num_classes)
   
def forward(self, x_3d):
    hidden = None

    # Iterate over each frame of a video in a video of batch * frames * channels * height * width
    for t in range(x_3d.size(1)):
        with torch.no_grad():
            x = self.resnet(x_3d[:, t])  
        # Pass latent representation of frame through lstm and update hidden state
        # Hidden state keeps record of information learned from prior frames
        out, hidden = self.lstm(x.unsqueeze(0), hidden)         

    # Get the last hidden state (hidden is a tuple with both hidden and cell state in it)
    x = self.fc1(hidden[0][-1])
    x = F.relu(x)
    x = self.fc2(x)

    return x
```

Comment: do you understand what an LSTM is? do you understand that it has internal state? those questions should not be answered with "yes" until you've reviewed thoroughly.